# Jupyter doesn't let me type the left square bracket

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook

Recently I have installed Jupyter Notebook on my Mac for didactical use and I've noticed a problem: doing
`list =` 
Jupyter doesn't let me type the left square bracket, and if I type that in a new line it allows me to type, for example:

```
[]
```

I've just tried to reinstall completely Jupyter from the prompt using Homebrew and it doesn't worked. How can I do?

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7243

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue:

**https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15744**

You can do:

```
Settings → Settings Editor → JSON Settings Editor → Keyboard Shortcuts → User → paste → save
```

paste:

```
{
  "shortcuts": [
    {
      "args": {},
      "command": "inline-completer:next",
      "keys": [
          "Alt ]"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-mod-completer-enabled",
      "disabled": true
    },
    {
      "args": {},
      "command": "inline-completer:previous",
      "keys": [
          "Alt ["
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-mod-completer-enabled",
      "disabled": true
    },
    {
      "args": {},
      "command": "inline-completer:invoke",
      "keys": [
          "Alt \\"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-mod-completer-enabled",
      "disabled": true
    }
  ]
}
```

**https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/15744#issuecomment-1999433752**